# WPF Data binding: How to data bind a collection?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

You may read the complete structure of my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257542/wpf-data-binding-how-to-organize-projects-and-classes-in-a-solution), but here's the quick reference:

1. I made a class `Account.cs` in the `Entities` class library.
2. I made a class library `Core` with a class `AccountController.cs` which gets the 
   accounts from the Sql Server tables.
3. I made a class `AccountWindowController.cs` in the `Gui.Wpf.Controllers` class library. 
   It contains the `List<Account> Accounts` property and calls for the `GetAccounts()` 
   method in the `AccountController` to fill that list.
4. Finally, I made a `AccountWindow.xaml` in the `Gui.Wpf` class library. This WPF window 
   contains a `ListBox` named `AccountsListBox`.

I want to data bind the list box from `AccountWindow` to the list in the `AccountWindowController`, but I don't know how. Here's the relevant code:

**AccountWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Gui.Wpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controller="clr-namespace:Gui.Wpf.Controllers"
    Title="Accounts" 
    Width="350" 
    MinWidth="307" 
    MaxWidth="400" 
    Height="500" >

    <Window.Resources>
        <controller:AccountWindowController
            x:Key="AccountsCollection" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox 
            Name="AccountsListBox" 
            Margin="12,38,12,41" 
            ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AccountsCollection}" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**AccountWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Gui.Wpf.Controllers.AccountWindowController();
    }
}
```

**AccountWindowController.cs**

```
public class AccountWindowController
{
    //This event is handled in the AccountController.cs 
    //that sets the Accounts property defined below.
    public event EventHandler GetAccounts;

    private List<Account> accounts;
    public List<Account> Accounts
    {
        get
        {
            GetAccounts(this, new EventArgs());
            return accounts;
        }
        set
        {
            this.accounts = value;
        }
    }

    //Constructor
    public AccountWindowController()
    {
        new AccountController(this);
    }
}
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` needs to be an `IEnumerable`.  The `AccountsCollection` resource is a class that contains the property you want to use.  In order to do this, you need to bind to that property, and use the resource as the source of the binding:

```
<ListBox Name="AccountsListBox"
         Margin="12,38,12,41" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=AccountsCollection}}" />
```

You should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the AccountWindowController
 (and raise `PropertyChanged` in the Accounts setter) so that if you set the Accounts property, the `ListBox` will rebind to the new collection.  And if the Accounts collection is modified at runtime, it should be an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Abe, thanks so much! Everything is clear to me now and it works; much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're nearly there with it. Try changing

```
ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AccountsCollection}" />
```

Into

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=AccountsCollection}, Path=Accounts}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matthew. Changing the code resulted in the compile error with the error message: Error Unknown property 'Path' for type 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension. Should I change something else as well?

Comment: Apologies, I'd missed a bit out. Please try again.